# Unable to upload a file which has <input type="file"> on Firefox Browser

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

**EDIT: Updated with error**
I am trying to upload a file using webdriver in Java. I have set up everything but it does not work on Firefox.

```
WebElement uploadFile = nav.getWebDriver().findElement(FileScreenPage.UploadFileButton);
uploadFile.sendKeys(resourceDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + organisationName + "/" + FileName);
```

I tried all the solutions from stack and other websites it still not working.
Above script fails but it works perfect on ChromeDriver.
Could some one please help to fix this problem in firefox browser?
I am using **latest 3.14** version of selenium webdriver.

Error:
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element  is not reachable by keyboard
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'ip-172-20-88-189.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:8f9:2eef:3cae:f8d7%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.3', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 61.0.2, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.23.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 39082, moz:profile: /var/folders/6n/crr9n8x936b..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, platformVersion: 17.4.0, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}
Session ID: 47306e6e-3569-5645-8c70-fc214c2cfdd0

Comment: can you attach the exception when you try to upload the file. Also will be good to post html sample from firefox browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
WebElement uploadFile = nav.getWebDriver().findElement(FileScreenPage.UploadFileButton);
driver.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys(path to file);
```

Another solution is to implement autoit 3 or robot framework upload.
There is plenty examples around.

Comment: Tried. it is not working